# Running a C# Selenium test with PhantomJs on AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, phantomjs

I've created a new Visual Studio project for a .NET Core AWS Lambda function. I would like to run a Lambda function which uses PhantomJs to test a website is responding correctly.

I've added these NuGet packages:

[image: Nuget Packages]

And created this basic function:

```
public class Function
{
    public string FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        IWebDriver webDriver = GetWebDriver();
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://test.com");
        Console.WriteLine(webDriver.Url);
        return webDriver.Url;
    }

    private IWebDriver GetWebDriver()
    {
        PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
        PhantomJSDriverService defaultService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        defaultService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        defaultService.LoadImages = false;
        return new PhantomJSDriver(defaultService, options);
    }
}
```

I can get the test working fine locally, but on AWS I'm struggling to get past this error:

> {   "errorType": "DriverServiceNotFoundException",   "errorMessage":
>   "The file /var/task/phantomjs does not exist. The driver can be
>   downloaded at http://phantomjs.org/download.html",   "stackTrace": [
>       "at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService..ctor(String servicePath, Int32 port, String driverServiceExecutableName, Uri
>   driverServiceDownloadUrl)",
>       "at OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriverService..ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port)",
>       "at HealthCheck.Function.GetWebDriver() in C:\Git\LambdaTest\HealthCheck\Function.cs:line
>   28",
>       "at HealthCheck.Function.FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context) in
>   C:\Git\LambdaTest\HealthCheck\Function.cs:line
>   20",
>       "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"   ] }

The `phantomjs.exe` file is included in the uploaded package, but I don't know what path I need to be providing?

Comment: It looks like the exe isn't being included in the package uploaded to AWS. Unfortunately, this then leads to a follow on questions -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989452/how-to-include-exe-file-from-nuget-in-net-core-aws-lambda-package