# How to include exe file from Nuget in .NET Core AWS Lambda package?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, phantomjs

I've added Selenium.PhantomJS.WebDriver to a .NET Core AWS Lambda function which outputs `phantomjs.exe` to the bin folder when built locally. However, when I publish the project to AWS, the file is not included in the package. How do I tell AWS Toolkit this file needs to be included within the package?